# Where should I ask general home / connectivity / electronics devices related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This is in reference to the question on Super User ([Transferring smart TV's audio to bluetooth headset](https://superuser.com/questions/882508/transferring-smart-tvs-audio-to-bluetooth-headset)) which is currently on hold. Is there no place on Stack Exchange for such a question?

The original question reads like this:

> I am having LG 32LB5820 smart TV and Nokia BH 121 & byte corseca dm5710bt headset. I want to stream my TV's audio to my headphones. I am quite unsure what should I be looking for. I thought I need bluetooth transmitter. But still I want some standard / reliable / cost-effective solution. I live in India and I didnt get much recommendations from stores. Also want to know how I can stream audio to more than one headsets at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty broad and difficult to answer, especially when you note this:

> I am quite unsure what should I be looking for. But still I want some standard / reliable / cost-effective solution

It doesn't aim on directly solving particular problem (e.g. you found out how to transfer the audio to the bluetooth headset, did everything you could and got some error and ask about it there), but looking for recommendations, which are off-topic on SE, except [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (where your question would be off-topic too).

I am afraid there is no place for such questions on SE. Explain what you have tried and what went wrong, be specific, "share your research", as SU sidebar says when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any community right now for your question.  There might be in the future, however, as there is a [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) proposal that is currently in the commitment phase.

But even if the Hardware Recommendations proposal makes it into the Beta phase, your question may still be closed for being unclear.  You state yourself that "I am quite unsure what should I be looking for."  If you can do a little more research and determine the exact type of hardware component you need (whether it is a bluetooth transmitter or something else), then you could phrase your question as a request for a recommendation for a reliable/cost-effective bluetooth transmitter (or whatever hardware component it is that you need).  That type of a question would be on-topic for Hardware Recommendations, assuming it is able to move into the Beta phase.